# Como posso criar um formulario que tenha um contador e armazene as informações em banco

Tags: php, sql, contador

gostaria de uma ajuda.
Estou tentando criar uma página que calcule o tempo que a pessoa gasta em algumas tarefas que estará disponível em um formulário, dai a pessoa seleciona a tarefa e clica em  inicio onde começa a calcular o tempo gasto através de um cronometro podendo pausar e parar e que estas informações sejam armazenadas em um banco para que depois eu consiga consultar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, montei um script que conta o tempo, pausa, retoma e para. Ao parar envia os dados para o arquivo que fará o insert no bd

```
<script>
    var estado = true; //estado do cronometro
    var tempo = 0; //tempo atual

    setInterval("mostrar()", 1000);

    function mostrar(){
        if(estado) {
            tempo += 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = tempo+"s";
    }

    function play(botao){ //pausa e retoma a contagem
        if(estado) {
            estado = false;
            botao.value = "retomar";
        }
        else {
            estado = true;
            botao.value = "pausar";
        }
    }

    function salvar(){ //envia os segundos para a página que irá salvar o resultado;
        $("#res").load("salvar.php", {tempo:tempo}); //recebe $_POST['tempo'] na pagina com o insert
    }

</script>

<input type="button" value="pausar" onclick="play(this)"/>
<input type="button" value="pausar" onclick="salvar()"/>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Somente para ter uma idéia!

Comment: Obrigado pela força Paul